# Found a check in a parking lot, what should I do?

Tags: check, paycheck, personal-check

I think it got discarded because it's only worth $7. But still at least for future reference what should I do when I find someone else's check?

What is the proper way to 6 it to someone? Should I try to return it to the sender or the receiver?

Comment: Add three zeroes and cash it :-)

Comment: Last time I found a purse in a parking lot, I took it to the supermarket customer service desk.

Comment: These days the check may already have been deposited using a smartphone camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipient might be tough, not all checks I receive will have my address. If it does, and you're inclined, just mail it to them or drop it off if you are nearby. 
If not, I might just return to sender.

This all depends on the nature of the check, if it's a refund/rebate check from a big company, mailing it back may be pointless.